# how could I put an element in PL/SQL

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, element, apex

Im trying in Apex to set the value of a page element in a PL/SQL package for an update. Is es possible?
Let's say, the element is result
and would be refered like this
"begin
update table1 set field1 = result where..... --something like this.
end;"
It is also possible to set value of this element in a page item. But a page item in Apex could only be upto 32k. And the value of the result is often much longer than 32k.
Could anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the [APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/SET_SESSION_STATE-Procedure.html#GUID-ECF66FA6-91DF-4463-A7DC-EFFB3E49A5D1) procedure to set the value of your page item. It only accepts up to 32k as you stated so you will need to truncate your value down to 32k.

```sql
begin
  apex_util.set_session_state('my_item','myvalue');
end;
```

If the full >32k string needs to be displayed, you can store it into a CLOB column (maybe using [APEX_COLLECTION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/APEX_COLLECTION.html#GUID-859B488C-2628-44D7-969F-50872C685B76)) and select the value on your page.

Comment: the value is not stored in a page item but only a html element on the page. I try to put this element into a PL/SQL package. So I think the function set_session_state is not suitable.

Comment: The element is only a html element, is rendered after the page is loaded, something like <div>result</div> and could be much longer as 32k. For this reason the value can't be put into a page item. But I want to put this value in the database. Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain this with an example.
If you are trying to insert the > 32K data on click of a button the follow the below steps.

1. Create a dynamic action on click of the button.
2. Create a true action. Type -> JavaScript code.
3. Paste the below code.

```
var clobData  = $('#YOUR_DIV_ID').text();
var chunkData = apex.server.chunk(clobData);

if ( !$.isArray( chunkData ) ) {chunkData = [chunkData];}

apex.server.process("SAVE_DATA", {f01: chunkData},
 {
    dataType : 'text',
    success : function (pData) {
         apex.message.showPageSuccess('Saved Successfully');
 },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                   var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                   console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
 },
    loadingIndicatorPosition: "page"
});
```

4. Create an AJAX Callback process. Name it as SAVE_DATA. Paste the below PL/SQL code.

```
DECLARE
LO_CLOB     CLOB;
LO_TOKEN  VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(LO_CLOB, FALSE, DBMS_LOB.SESSION);

   FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT
   LOOP
        LO_TOKEN := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i);

        IF LENGTH(LO_TOKEN) > 0
        THEN
             DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(LO_CLOB, LENGTH(LO_TOKEN), LO_TOKEN);
        END IF;
   END LOOP;

   UPDATE T_EMPLOYEE
      SET DESCRIPTION = LO_CLOB; 
END;
```

**Note: You can change the AJAX callback PL/SQL code as per your need. This is my test code**

If you want more information on how to display and edit CLOB content using page Items you can visit my blog
https://akilramesh.blogspot.com/2021/06/display-and-edit-clob-content-in-oracle.html